# WPF programmatically send KeyDown event to control with Key + CTRL modifier

Tags: c#, wpf

**How do I programmatically raise a `CTRL`+`+` KeyDown event?**

In WPF, I can send a KeyDown event to a control by using the following code:

```cs
void SimulateKeyEvent(WebControl webControl, Key key, RoutedEvent routedEvent)
{
    var eventArgs = new KeyEventArgs(
        KeyBoard.PrimaryDevice, 
        KeyBoard.PrimaryDevice.ActiveSource, 
        0,
        key);
    eventArgs.RoutedEvent = routedEvent;
    webControl.RaiseEvent(eventArgs);
}

public void ZoomInOnWebControl()
{
    SimulateKeyEvent(this.myWebControl, Key.OemPlus, KeyBoard.KeyDownEvent);
}
```

However, I can't find documentation anywhere on how to send the event using code with a modifier like `Key.LeftControl`.

I have also tried sending multiple events in a row like it would happen when actually pressing CTRL + OemPlus,  but it didn't work as I intended:

```
    SimulateKeyEvent(this.myWebControl, Key.LeftCtrl, KeyBoard.PreviewKeyDownEvent);
    SimulateKeyEvent(this.myWebControl, Key.LeftCtrl, KeyBoard.KeyDownEvent);
    SimulateKeyEvent(this.myWebControl, Key.OemPlus, KeyBoard.PreviewKeyDownEvent);
    SimulateKeyEvent(this.myWebControl, Key.OemPlus, KeyBoard.KeyDownEvent);
    SimulateKeyEvent(this.myWebControl, Key.OemPlus, KeyBoard.PreviewKeyUpEvent);
    SimulateKeyEvent(this.myWebControl, Key.OemPlus, KeyBoard.KeyUpEvent);
    SimulateKeyEvent(this.myWebControl, Key.LeftCtrl, KeyBoard.PreviewKeyUpEvent);
    SimulateKeyEvent(this.myWebControl, Key.LeftCtrl, KeyBoard.KeyUpEvent);
```

On the myWebControl WebBrowser, I have events attached that output when all four of these events fire and during the events, the code simulates the click properly but the modifier key (`Control`) is never added.

Comment: Are you using InputSimulator?  It should be something like SimulateKeyDown(VirtualKeyCode.CONTROL); SimulateKeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.OEMPLUS); SimulateKeyUp(VirtualKeyCode.CONTROL);
There is also a SimulateModifiedKeyStroke function that can handle special situations.

Comment: No I am not using input simulator